# angular-translate multiple keys in one element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, translate

In my application I am pulling translations keys from a single cell in a database table and displaying them dynamically in a setting page. Most will only have one key in the display object but there will be a number of entries that would have multiple.

Is there a way in angular-translate to have one element host multiple keys and translate them?

en.json={"title1":"balance","title2":"other stuff"}

ctrl.list=[{display:"title1 title2"}]

```
<tbody class="validation-table-body">
  <tr ng-repeat="entry in ctrl.list">
    <td class="validation-name" >
      {{entry.display | translate}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

displayed:

```
<td>title1 title2</td>
```

expected:

```
<td>balance other stuff</td>
```

I am just trying to get this to work before trying to add a comma or something to display.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in the translate directive at least:

```
<ANY translate="{{toBeInterpolated}}"></ANY>
```

toBeInterpolated is the name of the key to be looked up.

Ref:https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/05_using-translate-directive